# generic method access hidden property in c#

Tags: c#

I'm currently having trouble and I have no clue how to fix it.

I have 2 classes:

```
class A 
{
 public string MyParam { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
  public new string MyParam { get { return base.MyParam != null ? base.MyParam.Substring(1) : null; } }
}
```

When I try to access the B.MyParam it works when I have a the correct type, but in most of my methods I have a generic type
with :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class A
        {
            public string MyParam { get; set; }
        }

        public class B : A
        {
            public new string MyParam
            {
                get { return base.MyParam != null ? base.MyParam.Substring(1) : null; }
            }
        }
        public static void MyMethod<T>(T variable) where T : A
        {
            Console.WriteLine(variable.MyParam);//this print hello
            Console.WriteLine((variable as B).MyParam);//this print ello (exactly what i want)
            Console.WriteLine(typeof(T)); // this print ConsoleApplication1.Program+A
            Console.WriteLine(variable.GetType()); // this print ConsoleApplication1.Program+B

            // so i need something like that

            Console.WriteLine((variable as variable.GetType()).MyParam); // this line is invalid
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            A a = new B();
            a.MyParam = "Hello";
            Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());
            MyMethod(a); 
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it? 
Thank you in advance.

EDIT: it seems that what i want is :

```
 dynamic variable2 = Convert.ChangeType(variable, variable.GetType());
 Console.WriteLine(variable2.MyParam);
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. If A inherits B, why is it's property marked as virtual, while B is marked as new? I think B should inherit A in this case....

Comment: Why is `B` redefining the property with `new`? If it used `override`, you'd get the correct definition regardless of whether it was treated as an `A`.

Comment: You should definitly have a look on inheritance and overriding, in particular on the differences between `override`, `virtual` and `new`.

Comment: Your code does not compile. I suspect you mean `class B : A`, and `mymethod` should be generic (`mymethod<T>`). In the unlikely case that this is really the object model you have to work with, you can use `as` and a check to get what you want, but explicitly having to check the type in a generic method is a sign that you're doing something wrong. This is exactly the thing virtual members are designed to solve.

Comment: yes there is an error it's B that inherit from A >< i need A to stay old value and B to get the new one (that work correctly) but for the moment the only way i know to get what i want is to cast my variable to B i need something generic in case of another class C something like ((myvariable.GetType())myvariable).MyParam. In fact when i try to access variable.GetType() it tell me it's a B (normal), intelisens show me that there is two MyParam (A one and B one) but when i use B.MyParam it give me A.MyParam

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn´t make any sense. If `A` inherits from `B` you´ll need `A` to **override** the base-implementation for your property. So I´ll assume you should rethink your inheritance-chain.

You can use `override` for this. Thus when your `variable`-parameter is of your base-class (I renamed that to `A`) you´re calling the base-method, if it´s a derived instance  (here `B`) you´re calling the override:

```
class A
{
    public virtual string MyParam { get; }
}

class B : A // note here that B derives from A, not the other way round
{
    public override string MyParam 
    { 
        get { return base.MyParam != null ? base.MyParam.Substring(1) : null; },
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

EDIT: While `new` intrduces a new member which (accidentally) has the same name (and signature) as the base-member it effectivly hides the base-member. Thus you effectivly have *two* members. Your only way to indicate which member should be used is by casting your instance to the desired class from which you need the implementation. However this somehow breaks the purpose of generics as the generic member has to know the exact types that are possible for the type-parameter.

Anyway this seems like broken design to me, as you´re actually creating a new member which has another *meaning*. So you should also give it a new *name*.

Comment: my bad B inherit from A. B.MyParam hide A.MyParam i don't want to overide it just access to B.MyParam

Comment: @ErwanJoly What do you think the `override` does (as `new` also, btw.)? Why don´t you want to override? It´s exactly what you should do. Depending on `variable` is, your execution will jump to either the base or the overriding implementation.

Comment: new hide the A MyParam that's exactly what i want, override change the value and i don't want to change it. i need for exemple (A)variable.MyParam == "Hello" and (B)variable.MyParam == "ello" it works correctly like that but when i use T (so not casted) it take the A type so it give me Hello instead of ello...  For the moment the only thing that work is if(variable is B){ B newvar = variable as B; newvar.MyParam} but i will add C D E F with the same system as B so i dont want to copy past a type check in a generic method

Comment: @ErwanJoly See my edit. In short you *have* to cast `variable` to your desired type in order to execute the hiding member instead of the base one.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your generic method, I think all you need is an interface.

```
public interface IMyParam
{
    string MyParam { get; set; }
}
```

Your classes.

```
class A : IMyParam
{
    public virtual string MyParam { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
    public override string MyParam
    {
        get { return base.MyParam != null ? base.MyParam.Substring(1) : null; }
    }
}
```

And your method, won't need to be generic.

```
public void MyMethod(IMyParam variable)
{
    // Your logic here, for example.
    Console.WriteLine(variable.MyParam);
}
```

Calling your method.

```
A a = new A();
a.MyParam = "Hello";

B b = new B();
b.MyParam = "Hello";

A ab = new B();
ab.MyParam = "Hello";

MyMethod(a); // Prints Hello
MyMethod(b); // Prints ello
MyMethod(ab); // Prints ello
```

Comment: I edited my original post. Now it should be easier to understand. My problem is not on the variable initialisation and when i don't use T but the correct type it works exactly like i want it to work but it seems that T variable.MyHiddenProperty access to the base property instead of the hidden one even if T is a inherited class

Comment: @ErwanJoly You need to use override if you want to access B.MyParam instead of A.MyParam.